# Tube size and tyre size mismatch

Tags: tire, wheels, rims, innertube, hybrid-bike

I have spares of 700x25C tube for my old bike. I bought a new hybrid bike. Can I use them for my new bike with tyre size 700x35C?

Comment: Keep those spares on your old bike, and get new spares for the new bike.

Answer (score 2):

What does the tube’s packaging say?

Usually they are specified to work for a relatively wide range of widths. It will says something like “18-622 to 25-622”.

A few percent above the spec usually works fine (e.g. using a 25mm width tube in a 28mm wide tyre). But if 25mm is the maximum for your tube then a 35mm tyre is probably way too wide and the tube is going to explode during the first full inflation.

Comment: Also consider the valve type (therefore its width) and possibly the valve length may be a factor with longer being okay, and shorter possibly not extending beyond the rim

Comment: Maybe not explode straight away, but will be very fragile due to being very stretched.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава: I’ve been using Schwalbe SV20 tubes (extralight, 18–25mm width) with 28mm Conti GP 4 Seasons for quite some time. I had one sudden failure on a really hot summer day in bright daylight which could be related to using them out of spec.